# Как внутри приложения вести счётчик количества входов в приложение?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mobile-development

Как внутри приложения вести счётчик количества открытий приложения, для дальнейшей реализации прогресса пользователя на основе количества входов в приложение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    //Счетчик количества запусков приложения
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if var numberOfLaunches = userDefaults.objectForKey("numberOfLaunches") as? Int {
        numberOfLaunches++
        userDefaults.setInteger(numberOfLaunches, forKey: "numberOfLaunches")
    } else {
        let n = 1
        userDefaults.setInteger(n, forKey: "numberOfLaunches")
    }
    print(userDefaults.objectForKey("numberOfLaunches") as! Int)

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте!

В простейшем случае для сохранения количества входов может пригодится класс [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/). В стандартной документации Apple есть немного примеров, в том числе и на языке Swift.

Хороший материал по теме в [этой статье](http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/).

Второй вариант - использовать вместо [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/) работу с БД. У iOS имеется стандартный фреймворк для работы Core Data. Хороший [вводный материал здесь](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial).

Для простой реализации этого более чем достаточно. Есть другие варианты сохранения:

1. На сервере (облаке)
2. В других хранилищах данных (не используя Core Data)

Далее для подсчета количества запуска приложения может пригодится вот этот метод UIApplicationDelegate [`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:).

Разместите простой счетчик (банальный инкремент) в этом методе и вы сможете добиться своей цели.

Если необходимо, то позднее смогу привести примеры кода.

Comment: Спасибо! Полистал, решил вопрос: